# ¿como puedo calcular la fecha de una publicacion ? en un formato comun

Tags: java, método, librería

El lenguaje java 
La ideas es simple tengo un now_date y tengo pub_date quiero calcular el tiempo entre ella y poner la informacion de la siguente manera:

si es unos minutos "hace 6 min"

si es unas horas "hace 6 h"

si es mas de 24 hora "ayer"

si es mas de 48 hora "el dom 25"

si es mas del dias de la semana "la semana pasada"

si es mas de un año "2017 jun"

si hay una libreria o metodo para hacerlo mas simple, me ayudarian mucho de momento los compare manualmente año con año, mes con mes, dia con dias, ..etc. Pero no es fiable de esta forma ya que con años biciestos me falla.

Comment: Hola Diego, necesitamos un [mcve] para ver qué es lo que quieres hacer y qué es lo que tienes hecho. Sin código, va a ser muy difícil orientarte. Por favor revisa la página de [ask] y edita la pregunta de forma acorde.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Java tiene un metodo que te puede ayudar

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

El mismo que devuelve la hora actual en milisegundos.

Puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
long tiempoInicial= tiempoDePublicacion;
long tiempoTranscurrido= System.currentTimeMillis() - tiempoInicial;
```

Hay métodos aún mas precisos. Eh aqui la documentación oficial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()